# An adjective for a method or a way of doing things that does not take unnecessary time or doesn't waste time?

Tags: word-request

I am looking for an adjective for *a* *method or a way of doing things that **does not take unnecessary time or doesn't waste time***?

Example:

> This journal has reviewed my paper without taking unnecessary time,
>   without wasting time. Their method is _____ .

Answer (score 4):

From Merriam-Webster:

> [**Efficient**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/efficient)
>   **1** : productive of desired effects
>   *especially* : capable of producing desired results with little or no waste (as of time or materials)
>
> [**Productive**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/productive)
>   **1** : having the quality or power of producing especially in abundance

Comment: I added actual links and block-quote formatting to your answer.

Comment: Thanks, new to this. Is that how the formatting should be?

Comment: It doesn't have to look exactly like that. The main point is that there is a quotation and that you provide accreditation and a link. (Assuming that all of those things are possible.)